# C++ default constructor does not initialize pointer to nullptr?

Tags: c++

I wonder if I have a `A*` member in my class, shouldn't it we set to `nullptr` automatically if I have a constructor of my class in this form:

```
class MyCLass
{
    A* m_pointer;

public:
    MyCLass()
    {
    }
};
```

Does it matter if I do `MyCLass* o = new MyCLass;` or I do  `MyCLass* o = new MyCLass();` in C++11?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: You don't need an explicit pointer in the first place, just use `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 What makes you think that this class should be the exclusive owner of the pointed to object?

Comment: @JamesKanze Unless there is evidence otherwise I would suggest he use that class.

Comment: It _will_ be set to `nullptr` if you just mention it in the initializer_list, no exlicit value needed: `MyCLass() : m_pointer() { }`

Comment: @0x499602D2 Why?  It's very exceptional for an `std::unique_ptr` to be appropriate in a class.  If the object lifetime should correspond exactly to that of the class, then just make the object a member, and don't use a pointer at all.

Comment: @JamesKanze My suggestion was a response to his question about *pointers* inside of a class. If he wants to use a *pointer* inside of a class then my first suggestion would be to use a `std::unique_ptr`. I don't know his situation to say it's better to use an actual `A` object, but that's not what the question's about.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I don't know his actual situation either, but since the cases where `std::unique_ptr` would be appropriate are very rare, I certainly wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @JamesKanze You wouldn't recommend `std::unique_ptr` in place of a raw pointer? Not sure I follow.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Not in the general case.  `std::unique_ptr` is very useful for certain specific cases, almost always as a local variable, but it certainly isn't appropriate for generic use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pointers are "POD types"...a.k.a. "Plain Old Data".  The rules for when and where they are default-initialized are summarized here:

[Default initialization of POD types in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212261/default-initialization-of-pod-types-in-c)

So no.  It doesn't matter what your constructor for a class is, if it's a raw pointer as a member of the class.  You aren't actually instantiating the class.  So members like `Foo *` or `std::vector<Foo> *` or anything ending in * will not be initialized to nullptr.

The smart pointer classes are not POD.  So if you use a `unique_ptr<Foo>` or a `shared_ptr<Foo>` that is creating instances of classes, that do have a constructor that makes them effectively null if you do not initialize them.

> Does it matter if I do MyCLass* o = new MyCLass; or I do  MyCLass* o = new MyCLass(); in C++11?

One question per question, please.

[Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

Comment: But if I don't define a constructor at all, I guess it will be initialized to `nullptr` by compiler generated default CTOR, right?

Comment: @Narek In that case you would need `MyClass m{};` or `MyCLass* m = new MyClass();` to ensure data members such as pointers are zero-initialized, i.e. you need to *value-initialize* the object.

Comment: @Narek Nope.  You could easily read with a search like "what all exactly does a default constructor do, and when is it invoked?" and find the likes of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417065/does-the-default-constructor-initialize-built-in-types)

Answer (score 3):

The default constructor, if compiler-generated or defaulted, will default-initialize all members. Any user-defined constructor will similarly default-initialize all members that don't have an explicit initializer in the initializer-list.

To default-initialize means "call the default constructor for classes, leave everything else uninitialized".