# How can I initialize a templated type to zero out POD data or default construct non-POD data?

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

Given a templated C++ function in C++-03:

```
template <typename data>
void example(data arg) {
  // How to get POD zero initialized and non-POD, default constructor?
  data x();
  ...
}
```

How can I zero out a templated argument if it is POD (e.g. `int` gets a `0`, `float` gets a `0.0`, etc.) or, for non-POD, use its default constructor?

I see with class members, this is handled as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15212351/115751) with:

```
struct X
{
   int x;
};

X x;        //x.x is not initialized
X y = X();  //y.x is 0
```

But in this situation, the variable is not a member of a class, so how do you correspondingly get this effect of initializing a POD typed variable and default constructing a non-POD typed variable?

Comment: Are you attempting to clear `arg` (as in `arg = 0;` for some specific types), or attempting to declare a variable of the same type as `arg`, and value-initialising that? If the former, what's `x` doing there? If the latter, what's `arg` doing there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default initialization of POD types in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212261/default-initialization-of-pod-types-in-c)

Comment: @PiotrS. Please post answers as answers, not as comments. It may unnecessarily call the copy constructor, though. Depending on what specifically the OP is after, there are some other options.

Comment: @hvd then let's wait for the OP's clarification

Comment: @Piotr S You have the correct answer here. Post is as answer :)

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Oops, code is corrected now to declare a variable of same type as arg and give a zero default for POD and a default constructor for non-POD.

Comment: I'm curious, any reason why you aren't accept Piotr S's answer? Are you anticipating potentially having uncopyable types, or don't want the overhead? I have a potential solution, but it's not beautiful, so I wanted to see why this didn't work first.

Comment: @NirFriedman PiotrS has not created an answer, just a comment thus far, so I cannot accept anything related to that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to formally "accept" his "answer". I just mean, he offered a solution above in the comments, does that work for you?

Comment: @NirFriedman Yes, I'm using `data x = data();` for non-`const` case and also `const T& data = T();` for case where `const` works.  It compiles, but I have not confirmed in the debugger that the value is zeroed out as desired.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `const T& data = T();`. This is guaranteed to avoid copies and such and `T` will be value-initialized, which is default construction for types that need it or 0 for all other types.

Comment: I'm curious, can anything be done with this if the OP needs to call non-const members on the created type? Would creating a non-const reference by const casting this reference by UB, or defined, since the actual temporary constructed is not const?

Comment: @NirFriedman, Yes, I have at least one case where data cannot be const as its value is conditionally updated, but I don't want a possible UMR, hence I need a default initialization.

Answer (score 1):

I'm so sorry to even write this solution, but you could do it using boost and type traits to literally have a different code path for each:

```
template <class T>
void f(typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_pod<T>, int>::type = 0) {
  T t = T();
  g(t);
}

template <class T>
void f(typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_pod<T>, int>::type = 0) {
  T t;
  g(t);
}

template <class T>
void g(const T & t) {
  std::cerr << t.x << std::endl;
}
```

Maybe you should use the `is_trivially_constructible` trait instead of `is_pod`. I know this isn't exactly beautiful, but it should work, and scales fine. I assume the compiler will do something intelligent with performance, but if you are really concerned you can force g (which is where the rest of your function will be implemented) to be always inlined into f.

Comment: defaulted template parameters of a function are part of the C++11 standard, not available in C++03

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename data>
void example(data arg) 
{
     arg  = 0;
}
```

For non POD-s

1. define appropriate copy constructor which set to zero this object
2. overload "=" operator