# Is there a benefit to declaring the default constructor as default?

Tags: c++, constructor, aggregate

In C++17, does it make any difference to declare the default constructor as default in an aggregate, as in:

```
struct A {
   A() = default;
   int v;
};
```

vs relying on it being implicitly defined, as in:

```
struct A {
   int v;
};
```

I understand that in C++20, declaring the constructor causes A to not be an aggregate. As I am switching our build flag to C++20, I'd like to just remove the constructor declaration so the structs remain aggregates, but I'm wondering is this has any side effect?

Comment: Well, if you have another one, it saves you typing (or even not).

Comment: `A() = default;` is a user declared constructor, sometimes that matters

Comment: In C++17 there is no difference but in C++20 there is.  The real question you have to ask yourself is do you want your type to be considered an aggregate or not.

Comment: @greg_p In C++20 the class will not be an aggregate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special

Comment: You can use `type_traits` and `std::is_aggregate`, as [shown here](https://godbolt.org/z/bcnEqKhW5).

Answer (score 0):

> does it make any difference to declare the default constructor as default in an aggregate

No differences in this case. Regardless whether you explicitly writes a default constructor `=default`, the compiler generates the same thing, and your variable `v` is initialized to 0 anyway.

Comment: `v` will not be initialized to zero by the defaulted default constructor.

Comment: ok so it's "default" value is initialized when we define it eg `struct A a1;' ?

Comment: @artm There is no "_"default" value_". The constructor doesn't change the value of the `int` member at all (whether implicitly-defined or explicitly defaulted) and leaves it with an indeterminate value (or zero value if the object was zero-initialized beforehand).

Comment: For built in types like `int`, default initialization is no initialization, the `int` just has some garbage value.  `A foo;` leaves `v` with an indeterminate value.  `A foo{}` (or if you could write `A foo()`) value initializes `foo` and that will zero initialize `v`.

Comment: @NathanOliver so you mean in this case `v` is never initialised to zero - regardless of whether the default ctor is there or not?

there is this related answer talking about "value-initialised" - not sure if it's exactly the same here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3803288

Comment: If you do `A foo;` then yes, `v` will not be initialized as you are doing default initialization.

Comment: @NathanOliver and `A foo();` then `v` will be initialized - correct ?

Comment: Yes, except that you can't do `A foo()` as that declares a function.  You have to do `A foo{};` or `A foo = A();`